# Prove that conjugation of element of $GL(n, k)$ has specific form

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $G \subset GL(n, k), |k| = p^m, |G| = p^s \implies \exists C \in GL(n, k):$
$CAC^{-1}$ is upper triangular with 1 on main diagonal, where $A \in G$.
I remarked that $G$ may be Sylow subgroup, but is this enough to prove this problem? Is this remark correct?
I have no other ideas and I don`t know how finish this proof.

Comment: Yes, $G$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,k)$, the group of upper unitriangular matrices is such a Sylow subgroup, and all Sylow subgroups are conjugate, so you are done.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you for answer. Could you help me prove this more formally? Because I got it intuitively, but I`m not sure that can prove this well.

Comment: Which part of the argument do you not understand? The first and the third statements come directly from Sylow's theorems. To prove that the group $P$ unitriangular matrices form a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,k)$ you need to calculate the orders $|P|$ and $|{\rm GL}(n,k)|$. Can you do that?

Comment: @DerekHolt now this sounds pretty clear, I’ll try.